# php recursive function in class

Tags: php, class, recursion

This function works fine outside of a class. Ie simply define the function and call it. Yet when I add it to a class it no longer works - any help is greatly appreciated:

```
public function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;    

        if($needle===$value || (is_array($value) && $this->recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {

            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

obviously the **$this** is removed when not in a class.

Edit:
The error I an getting when using it in a class is:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   app\components\GenFun::recursive_array_search('9377907', 9378390)

My sole expectation from the function is that it returns any key (ie identifies that the needle exists in the haystack) - I actually dont care about the actual index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, "*it no longer works*" isn't a helpful metric by which to assist you in debugging your problem. Nor is "*it works fine*", since that doesn't tell us your definition of what *works* means to you. More precisely, these statements don't tell us what you expected the code to do that it's not doing, or what the code is doing that you did not expect.

To me this code is doing exactly what you've told it to do and the result of both a function as well as a class method (using the same code) are identical... [See the working 3v4l pastebin here](http://3v4l.org/rOl1T).

However, my guess is that your expectations may be different from what this code actually does. Specifically, this function will return at the very first match of the `$needle` in the `$haystack`. Such that the following array, returns `0` (_that is with a needle of `'foo'`).

```
$haystack = ['foo', ['foo', 'bar']];
```

It will also return only the key of the **outer-most** array in the `$haystack`. Meaning, the following array returns `0` as the key. Even though the actual match is in `$haystack[0][1][2]`

```
$haystack = [['bar',['quix','baz','foo'],'baz'],'quix'];
```

So depending on what you expected (the inner-most key, or the outer-most key), you may believe this function doesn't work.

So you'll need to clarify exactly what you want the code to do and provide some reproducible example of what didn't work (*and that includes the data used or arguments provided to the function*).

---

***EDIT:***

Hey, I'm glad you figured it out. Here are just a few suggestions to maybe help you refactor this code slightly as well...

So since you're looking for the existence of the needle in any part of the array and don't actually care about the key, you may want to make your intent more obvious in the logic.

So for example, always return a boolean (`true` on success and `false` on failure) rather than return `false` on failure and the key on success. This makes checking the function's result easier and clearer from the caller's perspective. Also, consider naming the function to describe it's intent more clearly (for example: `in_array_recursive` rather than `recursive_array_search` since we're not actually intent on searching the array for something, but proving that something is actually *in* the array). Finally, consider avoiding multiple return points in the same function as this makes debugging harder.

So a cleaner way to write the same code might be something like this:

```
public function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {

    $result = false;

    foreach($haystack as $value) {

        if(!is_array($value)) {
            $result = $strict ? $needle === $value : $needle == $value;
        } else {
            $result = $this->in_array_recursive($needle, $value, $strict);
        }

        if ($result) {
            break;
        }

    }

    return $result;

}
```

Now the caller simply does...

```
$arr = ['bar',['foo']];

if (in_array_recursive('foo', $arr)) {
    /* 'foo' is in $arr! */
} else {
    /* 'foo' is not in $arr... */
}
```

Making the code more readable and easier to debug. Notice you also don't have to use exact match if you wanted to add an optional argument for `$strict` at the end of the function there and also be more inline with `in_array`.

Comment: Hi Sherif - sorry for not being clear. I have edited my questions

Comment: Hey @nicky, I'm glad you figured it out. I updated the answer for you with a few suggestions that might help clean up the code a bit :) Hope that helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this was not working was due to the method by which I was defining $needle.

In my old code it would be input as an integer and in my new code it was a string. The === operator then obviously denied it as being the same. This is why you don't work at 2am :)